# Testing a general controller action using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's how my routes look like:

```
 /article/:id/:action     {:root=>"article", :controller=>"article/article", :title=>"Article"}
```

Here's how my controller looks like:

```
# app/controllers/article/article_controller.rb
class ArticleController < ApplicationController
  def save_tags
    # code here
  end
end
```

I want to test the save_tags action so I write my spec like this:

```
describe ArticleController do       
   context 'saving tags' do
     post :save_tags, tag_id => 123, article_id => 1234
     # tests here
   end
end
```

But when I run this spec, I get the error

```
ActionController::RoutingError ...
No route matches {:controller=>"article/article", :action=>"save_tags"}
```

I think the issue is the save_tags action is a general controller action, ie. there's no /article/:id/save_tags in routes.  What's the best way to test this controller action?

Answer (score 3):

You're spot on.  The issue is that you're looking for a route which doesn't have `:id` in it, but you don't have one.  You'll need to pass a parameter to the `post :save_tags` of `:id`, and given the above question, I believe it is what you are calling `article_id`.

Therefore, try changing your test to:

```
describe ArticleController do       
   context 'saving tags' do
     post :save_tags, tag_id => 123, id => 1234
     # tests here
   end
end
```

**Update**

Rails might be getting confused because you're using `:action` in your route and I believe `action` is either a reserved word or a word that Rails treats as special.  Maybe try changing your routes to:

`/article/:id/:method_name     {:root=>"article", :controller=>"article/article", :title=>"Article"}`

And your test to:

```
describe ArticleController do       
  context 'saving tags' do
    post :save_tags, { :tag_id => 123, :article_id => 1234, :method_name => "save_tags" }
    # tests here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response CDub.  I tried your test above but I'm still getting the same error: No route matches {:tag_id=>123, :action=>"save_tags", :controller=>"article/article", :id=>1234}

Comment: I'd hesitate to have `:action` in your routes as Rails may get confused as to what that means in your route...  Maybe try changing `:action` in your route to `:method_name` then pass in `:method_name => "save_tags"` in your test...  I'll make an edit to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a route to map to your controller actions

```
post '/article/:id/save_tags'
```

should work, or consider using resources helper to build your routes

```
# creates the routes new, create, edit, update, show, destroy, index
resources :articles

# you can exclude any you do not want
resources :articles, except: [:destroy]

# add additional routes that require an article in the member block
resources :articles do 
  member do 
    post 'save_tags'
  end
end

# add additional routes that do NOT require an article in the collection block
resources :articles do 
  collection do 
    post 'publish_all'
  end
end
```